# Solving Diophatine Equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^n+1=b^{n+1}$ and gcd$(n+1, a)=1$.

This is a problem from 1998 Indian olympiad (though I believe it is originally from Bulgaria or East Europe). It admits a purely elementary solution.

Comment: What have you tried on this problem?

Comment: @user675779: Please edit your post to$\;(1)\;$show what you tried$\;(2)\;$indicate where the problem comes from (e.g., if it's a problem from a competition, indicate which competition, which year, which problem number).

Comment: This is a problem from Indian olympiad. Why is it on hold? It's pretty well-defined as above, clear.

Comment: @TBTD: It was closed because the OP (user675779) showed no work. On this site, the OP is expected to include, as part of the post, some discussion (e.g., what was tried), not just a bare statement of the problem. Also, if the problem was from a competition, that should have been disclosed in the post itself, not just in a comment.

Comment: @quasi: 1) I disagree with what you say. What if OP had said, in the problem body: "I could not get anywhere, except the trivial factorization: "b^{n+1}-1=(b-1)(b^n+\cdots+1)$". I'd think people most likely would keep it open, yet the difference it makes is incremental to none.

2) Same here. Give him the benefit of the doubt. What if they don't know the source of the problem?

To add, it seems people really care about the cosmetics, not the gist of the problem, and that, they have allergy towards contest problems, something I completely dislike.

Comment: Since you guys are in an irrational way closed the question, I'll post my answer here: The only possibility is $(x,y,n)=(a^2-1,a,1)$. To see this, note that for $n=1$, these are indeed the only possibilities. Thus, take $n>1$. Now, $x^n=(y-1)(y^{n-1}+\cdots+1)$. Suppose $p\mid y-1$ is a prime. I claim that $p\nmid y^n+\cdots+1$. To see this, note: $y\equiv 1\pmod{p}\Rightarrow y^n+\cdots+1\equiv n+1\pmod{p}$. Since $p\mid x$ too, and $(x,n+1)=1$, we get the contradiction. Thus, $y^n+\cdots+1$ is a perfect $n^{th}$ power. However, this is impossible for $n\geq 2$: $y^n<y^n+\cdots+1<(y+1)^n$.

Comment: @TBTD: I agree that the MSE close system is flawed, and I didn't vote to close. In fact, I solved the problem (8 hours ago), but I didn't post my solution, since the OP gave no response to my request for context.

Comment: I got you. The thing is, I seriously don't like the way people vote for closing here. It is just annoying. Plus, if a big guy (will give no names here) posts a contest problem, saying this is an olympiad one but a good one, his question is very well welcomed. It really seems, it is a personal dilemma going on here, that annoys me.

Comment: This second part of my comments go for especially MathOverFlow forums. It also seems the way you phrase the problem really effects people's reaction (I know a French guy, whose posts are troll, but he knows the bug of MOF and whenever he puts a problem there, adds some spice to make it look like arising from his research, and people not only keep it open and answer, but also upvote and add to their favorites. I just think math should not be this way, this is like high-school girl approach.

Comment: @TBTD: Yes, the inconsistency is blatant. In a given $24$-hour period, some MSE questions with no context get welcomed and answered, while others get closed.

Comment: @TBTD: By the way, my solution was essentially the same as yours. I enjoyed the problem.

Comment: My also.....@quasi

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overkill, but... Mihăilescu's theorem, better known as Catalan's conjecture, says that the only two consecutive perfect powers are $8$ and $9$, but $a^n=8$ and $b^{n+1}=9$ don't give integer solutions, so $n>1$ is not possible. Then $n=1$, so $a+1=b^2$ and $a$ is odd, which has infinitely many solutions for all even $b$.